# TypeScript incorrectly assuming the value of a property after it is set

Tags: typescript

I have an object in TypeScript with a `boolean` property. When I set the object's value to `false`, TypeScript assumes it will *stay* false (at least until the end of the scope), even though it's able to be changed:

```js
const object = { property: true }; // Type is { property: boolean }

object.property = false; // Type is now { property: false }

function setObjectPropertyTrue(object: { property: boolean }) {
    object.property = true;
}

setObjectPropertyTrue(object);

if (object.property == true) { // ← tsc: "This condition will always return false"
    console.log("Object property is true!");
}
```

Here, the TypeScript compiler thinks the if statement will never succeed because as soon as I set the object's property to `false`, it assumes the property's type *becomes* `false`.

Of course I can cast `object.property` back to boolean in the if statement to fix the error, but this seems like a bad way of doing it? Ideally TypeScript wouldn't assume an object's property couldn't change after where it sees it is set.

Comment: Yeah, this is one of the reasons to prefer a more functional style in TypeScript whenever possible - avoiding mutation makes things so much easier

Comment: I'd generally agree: in this case the object is some singleton which would be difficult to make more functional. Still, it seems like TypeScript is making some poor assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no proper way to give TypeScript a type hint for the possible property modification in your exact implementation.

Since you said your object is a singleton, it might make more sense to have a setter function on the object itself and make the property private by using a class ([playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeB5ARgKwKbAC7QN4ChojoAHAJwEsA3MLdaAfXIHsT0yt4AuaZZ5kOjAA7aAF5oAMzAgI6ANyFCxOVhQZsABTKt2nACpkArugAUASgLFiWABYUIAOiY62HeOOhZjC5UQC++H7QAOboWNq67hZW1tBk4UZkonYOzixunMGBwaqRmfCmNCAmPHwCQsKWwUSpTi5RnJ7FJorWgTnAzMIQOAC2SGiYWDwI6sOewugA7nCDGlgWivgA9CvQA+PY6a56HhLSsgrQa9D5e9AA5A0Fl9AOpJQ0dNAiACbQ3SAeYMDA6FAKMhBNBphRUqJQJAYJcxkNsJcgpt4VhHHldtFDnJzEj5sM0eEthEMQYfBYghRJNBTMiFo4wsTGoVzOIJN4TCzcCd1sJmNB2DoyMouj0Ko4QMwQqYAEREx5M+4wdnoACE0vMin8QA)):

```js
class MyObject {
    private _property: boolean = false;
 
    setObjectPropertyTrue(){
      this._property = true;
    }

    getProperty(){
      return this._property
    }

    setProperty(value: boolean){
      this._property = value;
    }
}

const myObject: MyObject = new MyObject();

// myObject._property = false; // Property '_property' is private and only accessible within class 'MyObject'

myObject.setProperty(false)

myObject.setObjectPropertyTrue()

if (myObject.getProperty() == true) { // no error
  console.log("Object property is true!");
}
```

Note that I am **not** using `set` and `get` keywords, because in this case the same error occurs as can be seen in this [playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeB5ARgKwKbAC7QN4ChojoAHAJwEsA3MLdaAfXIHsT0yt4AuaZZ5kOjAA7aAF5oAMzAgI6ANz5CxAObocLNh3gAKAJQFiR6GXUBXMqKwALChAB0TMq3adFRgL5Kjcjc62cOjQgZug8fAJCwgbKxtA2do6arvDi0MGh7sRe0LHQvigY2AAK-ikAKmSh+oZx8bYOTi7aaVhVCnleeWpYpc2BMXUm5pb1iU0B8J3exL59k0EyoeH8giKDdQmNyS0SGR2e+F3AzMIQOAC2SGiYWDwIhbdpwugA7nDXRVj6ivgA9H9oMwbtgkmVdlIZHJ5NAAdB5iloAByCYpJHQOykSg0OjQEQAEyBwhAqTAwGA6CgFGQgmgrwoCVEoEgMCRDxBWCRSiuj1BO04rXa+B5HPs-NSEmksnocMkzDIFJgAAMTsJ8QyKKc6RQQCA8SBXmB4DBTFgLKIkVK5EildB2M4yEoASKvvY5uDAm1Qnp-n8Xbc3eoEdodFb0D7ff7QQUOcHOJVqhHVRBIvYQMwVDoo1gxR74BGKJJoFnPgHxeIJF7w3g8snU+nMwAiXl+fqpTFVgCEjb0ii8heL2fsPTjuj0Ffi7XHtSIdcEaYzOmbHKxbYxMC7Pb7QA). This behavior of TypeScript feels a bit weird to me overall. Almost like a bug or at least a lacking feature. Might be worth opening a GitHub issue for this, if you want to get to the root of this behavior.

---

#### Simple alternative for non-singleton object

If it is just a regular object and not a singleton, going for a more functional style by returning a new object might be good enough ([playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBA9gRgViAxpAvBA3hADgJylkHMATwC4IwcBXECAXwG4IB6ZiAFWIIgEsBnDNjwEiZCDChRQAQwB29AFALYCZADpc+QiQhoAZtOB8QTVhy61+EWVADugzSJLkDR2nSV6qs5DyjzjMAB5eCQwAAVhbWJ2ahAACiwAfRUw8hICKD1oUOQASkEIIoUiopxwKhx5TBLSurUG5NTkABpauqLHaPS49sUPZVzUCECQ1Qio0ViaeOawPIYlHmzZoY1JnRQ0ShoC9D7Efz4pEDVgKABzeIAiMbChLVFeAR2QAEJrhbqFOiA)):

```js
function setObjectPropertyTrue(p_object: typeof object) {    
    return { 
        ...p_object,
        property: true
    }
}

object = setObjectPropertyTrue(object);
```

Comment: Thanks, since you also seem to agree that the behaviour of TypeScript isn't ideal, I've [filed a bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45366) to see what the official explanation is.